# Incorrect display color when connecting computer to TV

Tags: windows-7, vga, tv, external-display, desktop-computer

I have a desktop running Windows 7. When I try to connect it to a Sony TV using VGA, the color on the TV's display changes. If I connect it back to a monitor, it looks proper.

What is happening?

Comment: I need more information regarding the > color of display on SONY TV changes In what way does it change? What are the color changes you witness? Here's a solution that may work: Go to Control Panel -> Personalization -> Display. In the left pane, click "Calibrate color" and follow the on-screen instructions. Kindly inform me if this is not helpful and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Will let you about the results for the solution that you have given. Currently when I connect the VGA to TV, the color of the display changes to some what yellowish.

Comment: Have you tried a different VGA cable? Tried a different desktop?

Comment: @Moses: Will try connecting my laptop and will post the results...